# Angular 2 subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

Can someone explain me difference between this two ways of subscription, first case

```
   this.incMatService.incomingMaterialUpdate$.subscribe((model) => {
        try {
            code here
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    this.incMatService.incomingMaterialNew$.subscribe((x) => {
        try {
            this.imForm = this.initImForm();
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    })
```

and second case

```
subscription: Subscription;
subscriptionToAdd: Subscription;
subscription = this.incMatService.incomingMaterialUpdate$.subscribe((model) => {
            try {
                code here
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
       subscriptionToAdd = this.incMatService.incomingMaterialNew$.subscribe((x) => {
            try {
                this.imForm = this.initImForm();
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
```

I know that in second case i have to unsubscribe(), i don't know how situation looks in the first case.

Other of code from my service

```
private updateIncomingMaterial = new ReplaySubject<IncomingMaterial>(0);

private addNewIncomingMaterial =  new Subject();

incomingMaterialUpdate$ = this.updateIncomingMaterial.asObservable();

incomingMaterialNew$ = this.addNewIncomingMaterial.asObservable();

updateIncMaterial(incomingMaterialToUpdate: IncomingMaterial) {
    this.updateIncomingMaterial.next(incomingMaterialToUpdate);
}

addNewIncMaterial(){
    this.addNewIncomingMaterial.next();
}
```

I emit this events in one component and subscripe in another one like i show in example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in the second case, you store the subscription in a variable, whereas you don't in the first case.

Whether you need to unsubscribe or not is unrelated. If the observable has a longer life-cycle than your component (i.e. it keeps existing and emitting events even after your component is destroyed), then you need to unsubscribe, and thus store the subscription in a variable to be able to do it. Otherwise you'll have a memory leak, and will keep executing code each time an event is emitted, for nothing.

Comment: So if I don't do it by the variable I become liable for a memory leak?

Comment: No. If you don't unsubscribe, you'll have a memory leak. And since you must unsubscribe, you must keep a reference to the subscription, and thus store it in a variable, in order to call unsubscribe() later.

Comment: So how to recognize which case is better, becouse like i understand in my first case i can't unsubscribe so it possible that i will have a memory leak.

Comment: So, don't you have your answer? Do you prefer a solution which leaks memory, or a solution which doesn't?

Comment: This one which doesn't :)

Comment: @JBNizet It is false to say "If you do not unsubscribe you have a memory leak". Observables emit events on `next()` calls and eventually complete with a `complete()` or `error()` call, but can also be cancelled early with `unsubscribe()`. As soon as an observable terminates by one of these three methods, all associated resources will be cleaned up too. While `unsubscribe()` allows you to cancel the subscription from the outside, you can also depend on completion from the source, or modify the source to complete with operators like `take()`, `takeUntil()`, `takeWhile()` etc.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's why I said in my answer: *If the observable has a longer life-cycle than your component (i.e. it keeps existing and emitting events even after your component is destroyed), then you need to unsubscribe*.

Comment: @JBNizet My point is that there are more options than just unsubscribing. `.takeUntil(onDestroy$)` for example would be just as good. (then you also need `var onDestroy$ = new AsyncSubject(); $onDestroy() { onDestroy$.next(); onDestroy$.complete(); }` to actually have a `onDestroy$`)

Comment: I agree completely. By doing that, the Observable you subscribe to completes when the component is destroyed, and you thus don't have to unsubscribe anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you simply lose reference tot he subscription, so you cannot even cancel it. Usually this is done on sources that end naturally anyway so there is no need to cancel. You can also modify the source to cancel when you no longer need it with [`.takeUntil(endEvent$)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil) instead of calling `.unsubscribe()`.

Comment: So how to recognize which case is better, becouse like i understand in my first case i can't unsubscribe so it possible that i will have a memory leak?

Comment: @Stefan If you use `takeUntil` properly, it will not leak either. Because when the observable inside `takeUntil` fires, it will complete and GC all resources associated with the stream.